# Assertion in selenium webdriver -report showing only falied methods, not passed methods

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide, testng-eclipse

In my selenium TestNG class, there are some
 methods, like method1, method2 etc.
 I have added fail and success conditions to each method.

```
public class TestNGClass {

public void method1(String value) throws Exception {

  if(value.equals("PASS"){
      org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(condition, message);
  }
}

//This is another method

public void method2(String value) throws Exception {

  if(value.equals("FAIL"){
    org.testng.Assert.fail(message);
  }
}
```

But after the TestNG class execution, in the Test-Output folder "Index.html" will be created, which shows only the failed methods. How to display the passed methods also (custom report) .?

```
Thank you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your test methods using @Test annotation. Modified Code Snippet:

```
public class TestNGClass {

@Test
public void method1(){
   Assert.assertTrue(condition, "Your Message goes here");
}

//This is another method
@Test
public void method2(){
  Assert.fail("Your Message goes here");
}
```

Now, you will have your testcases reported.